# inner join table with multiple foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Table film**

id_film

name

director

stars

year

ocjena

review

**table year**

id_year

year

**table genre**

id_genre

genre

**table film_genre**

id

id_film

id_genre

In table film "year" is foregin key to table year.
In table film_genre id_film and id_genre are foreign keys to tables film and genre. Since one movie can have multiple genres and one genre can have multiple movies,
I'm trying to get output from these tables to look like this...

name :

genre : for example. Drama , Action, History

director :

stars :

year :

Ocjena :

review :

I tried like this but it's not working cause if movie has got 3 genres (example. drama,action,history) it doesnt output all genres for one movie in single output, instead he output 3 times same movie with one genre in each output. can u help me please?

```
try{
            $upit=$veza->prepare("select a.name,d.genre as genre,a.director,a.stars,b.year,a.ocjena,a.review
                                  from film a 
                                  inner join year b on a.year=b.id_year
                                  inner join film_genre c on a.id_film=c.id_film
                                  inner join genre d on d.id_genre=c.id_genre");

            $upit->execute();
            $rezultat=$upit->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            foreach ($rezultat as $red) {

                echo "</br><strong> Name : </strong>" . $red->name; 
                echo "</br><strong> Genre : </strong>" . $red->genre; 
                 echo "</br><strong> Director : </strong>". $red->director; 
                 echo "</br><strong> Stars : </strong>". $red->stars; 
                 echo "</br><strong> Year : </strong>". $red->year; 
                 echo "</br><strong> Ocjena : </strong>". $red->ocjena; 
                echo "</br><strong> Review : </strong>".  $red->review; 
                echo "<pre></pre>";
                }



        } catch(PDOException $e){

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a GROUP BY a.id_film and have the genre names concatenated with GROUP_CONCAT(d.genre) as genres